# Understanding standard model and symmetry

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, standard-model, symmetry-breaking, higgs

I just want to know whether my understanding regarding standard model and symmetry is correct or utter nonsense.

1. The standard model is the (yet incomplete) Lagrangian of the
   universe.
2. The Lagrangian predicts symmetry regarding charge, parity and time.
3. Experiments show that the predicted symmetry is broken.
4. Hence we have to improve the standard model to make theory reflect
   reality.

Comment: I am sorry but these slogans sound rather vague, ambiguous, and superficial. It seems hard to associate them with the word "understanding". Understanding is a rather big word, very different from a Yes/No confirmation or refutation of 4 simple slogans. The 4 statements may be good for someone but not someone else. They're surely not enough for a physics student at a college to pass a particle physics exam etc.

Comment: 1) The standard model is merely a low energy effective field theory that does not include gravity. So, that's a negative. 2) Nope. The symmetries are chosen so that they describe the observed phenomenology correctly. There is no "prediction" going on here, at all. It's all a big fit. 3) Experiments and the standard model agree because the standard model is being made to agree. 4) That's the only thing that is correct, but it doesn't really make it a theory. A model fit is a model fit. It doesn't explain anything and can, at best, make predictions due to internal consistency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question that you have asked have some vague arguments as well as some partially true facts regarding Standard Model (SM).

First, Yes SM describes physics up to some energy scale which is 14 TeV. On the other hand, if we accept Plank energy ($~10^{18}$GeV) as a fundamental energy scale, then we can possibly expect new beyond the SM energy scale. A possible minimal extension of SM is left-right symmetric model based on $SU(2)_{\text{L}}\times SU(2)_{\text{R}}$, or Grand unified theories based on gauge group $SU(5)$ or $SO(10)$. Yet, predictions of these models (like proton decays) are not found in LHC or super kamiokande till date. Moreover in SM neutrinos are mass less (which is not true indeed!). Which clearly implies that yet something more to be discovered where SM is only a small part of it.

Regarding symmetry, SM (Lagrangian) took few experimental findings as its input. 
Say for example Parity. It was proved that weak interactions violate parity before SM Lagrangian was first written by Julian Schwinger based on $SU(2)$ gauge group, which later extended by his student S. Glashow to $SU(2)_{L}\times U(1)_{Y}$ . Parity violation manifests in SM through V-A (vector-axial vector) type of current. Another possible example is CP violation. Which is an experiment fact. Later it was shown-provided that third generation of quark exists, one can show the CP violation in SM via an a phase factor of CKM matrix. Roughly speaking SM is an example of phenomenological model of particle interactions.

In case of charge it is not clear which charge you are talking about. It could be weak isospin, electric charge, Noether charge. Please be specific.

For the symmetry breaking, it is enough to say that the symmetry $SU(2)_{L}\times U(1)_{Y}$ must be broken down to $U(1)_{em}$ via Higgs mechanism. Otherwise the whole point of discussing about the theory become pointless.

Last but not the least SM is complete within its energy range. What we can possibly expect is its extension. Therefore we don't need to improve it. Check this "hep-ph/0404165" paper for the precision test of SM.